How to Deploy Smart Contract on QBFT Besu network from Metamask?
I have configured my local private network with tryethernal and now trying to deploy smart contracts via remix.
Starting with simple ERC20 token when I click on deploy I get the following error:
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Returned error: Transaction processing could not be completed due to an exception: INVALID_OPERATION
[object Object]
Even I forcefully send the TX, the TX fails but I can see the deployed contract object in remix. Mint() function works but balance of token doesnt get updated.
Any clue of this problem?

sounds lke you have abug in your code, you didn't paste it here so no one can really help...

I have already debugged the problem and answered my own question. Please check

So the problem was that the fork information was mismatching b/w my genesis file and the remix. When I changed EVM Version in Remix to "Berlin" everything started working fine.
